# Browser freezing when pasting large data?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, excel, internet-explorer, copy-and-paste

I'm trying to paste data from an excel spreadsheet to an already existing SharePoint 2013 list.
The spreadsheet and the list have the same format and there are no conflicting values.

The problem is that the spreadsheet contains upwards of 10.000 entries and everytime I try to paste the data into the list the browser (Internet Explorer 11) freezes.

Is there any other way to copy the data into the list?

Comment: Test pasting few rows, I've found that Sharepoint struggles to update a lot of rows at once.  e.g. try pasting 50, then 100 and see how it goes.  You could also try pasting fewer columns and see if it can handle more rows that way.  Then paste in the other remaining column values later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to do the same as you (1000+ rows) and the behavior of the browser was exactly the same. After reading more carefully the documentation [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493258%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#ListLibrary) I found the following row for bulk operations via user interface:

> The user interface allows a maximum of 100 items to be selected for
>   bulk operations.

I think that is applicable and for pasting data in quick edit mode. When I paste less than 100 rows, everything works fine.

You can try to import the data with PowerShell script, or to use some third party tool for import. I don't think you will be able to import large data through the user interface of SharePoint.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. Pasting in lots of rows from an Excel sheet results in IE getting very slow or freezing (same happens with Chrome btw).

We are currently working on a (Nintex) Workflow to offer users a way to import larger XLS files automatically. Might be a workaround for you?

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting the from SharePoint as an Excel spreadsheet. Then edit it in excel and recreate the list using the completed excel sheet.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa

I haven't tried this yet so I would recommend a running test first to ensure it works correctly.

Note that this requires an additional Microsoft app and is not entirely an OOTB solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85856)